# Mark with color on grayscale image in Matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing, colors

I have a grayscale image (so an 2d numpy array with values between 0 and 1) which I usually show as follows:

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title(title)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Now I want to kind of "paint" over this image with one single color (to highlight some part). Is there a way to do this in Python (preferably matplotlib)?

For example I have the Shepp Logan Phantom ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp–Logan_phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp%E2%80%93Logan_phantom)), of which I want to mark the right black ellipse with a red edge. I do have an image containing only this edge (of the same size as the Phantom), so how can I "put" it with a color over the original gray scale image?

EDIT: I am actually using more complicated images with arbitrary shapes and not precise ellipses/circles, but suppose I want to highlight the following white parts of the image below (for which I cannot use perfect shapes) of the Shepp Logan phantom with red together with the rest of the Shepp Logan phantom as in the link:

[image]

Then my question is: how can I combine these two images (of which one should be colorized and the other one should be a grayscale image).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Is there a way to do this in Python (preferably matplotlib)?"_ Yes and yes. ፨ _"If so, let me know!"_ impossible because you do not say **exactly** what you want/need to do.

Comment: On a more constructive note... even if you used a grayscale for `imshow`,  whatever else you place on your figure will be in color.  So don't worry in advance and move on with your task :-)

Comment: If I understand you re Shepp-Logan phantom, you have to draw ellipses over the image, so you could look  at this example  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/shapes_and_collections/ellipse_demo.html ፨ Try your hand at it and ask more specific questions if you have difficulties.

Comment: I edited my question, since I am actually using more arbitrary shapes and not perfect ellipses like in the Shepp Logan.

Comment: If  you have to combine two _images_, you can draw (using again `imshow`) the second over the first, using a matrix of RGBA values and specifying total transparency where you want to see the lower layer image... If you use a REPL, just type `help(plt.imshow)` to have a look at the details.

Comment: Last comment from me... about the superposition of two images there is [a nice example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/layer_images.html) in Matplotlib documentation ፨ ciao

Comment: Your question is very jumbled up! You have a link to a grey image, which I presume is your starting image (?) and a white shape on a black background and you want a *"right black ellipse"* to somehow become red?